# Why does my System.Data.DataSet not work in a ForEach? (No GetEnumerator)

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, foreach

I have a puzzling error: I'm using a DataSet to return the result from a Stored Procedure, but I'm unable to use a ForEach to loop through the data... because apparently DataSet has no Enumerator

> Error  111 foreach statement cannot operate on variables of type 'System.Data.DataSet' because 'System.Data.DataSet' does not contain a public definition for 'GetEnumerator'

As far as I was aware, every DataSet had a publicly accessible Enumerator, and in fact there are multiple examples on the internet of a DataSet being used exactly this way! So I'm a little confused... do I have a configuration issue? Am I missing something obvious?

I'm using WebApi in .NET 4.6

Code (genericised) follows

```
        DataSet ds = new DataSet("DataSet");
        string connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["SQLConnection"].ConnectionString;
        using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
        {
            SqlCommand sqlComm = new SqlCommand("StoredProcedure", conn);
            sqlComm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Param1", 0);
            sqlComm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Param2", 1);                

            sqlComm.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

            SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter();
            da.SelectCommand = sqlComm;

            da.Fill(ds);
        }

        foreach (DataRow d in ds)
        {
            // Do things
        }
```

Comment: CAn you please show the code which gives this error ?

Comment: Huh? A DataSet is not a collection.  Are you confusing it with DataTable?

Comment: What do you expect when you loop `DataSet`? Loop through `Dataset.Tables` instead

Comment: @SLaks he must be.., that's why I have asked to paste code

Comment: Looks like that's it - doh! Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use it like this

```
foreach(DataRow dr in ds.Tables[0].Rows)
{
  // do your work here
}
```

Comment: Perfect, thanks - just me confusing the structure of a DataSet by the looks of things!

Comment: I can't yet :) you answered too fast - I will in ~8 minutes

Answer (score 0):

A Dataset does not inherit from System.Collections and is not enumerable.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.dataset(v=vs.110).aspx

However a Datatable does if you call AsEnumerable().

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatable(v=vs.110).aspx